# Key/Value pair with keys from a defined set

Tags: c#

Sorry if the wording of this question is incorrect; I'm coming from a Javascript/Typescript background.

What I'm looking to create is a set of key/value pairs which is immutable, where the IDE/compiler would know which keys are or aren't present in that list. I presume this is possible with a class, and maybe this is really the best option, but I'm interested to understand whether there are alternatives.

For instance, for the config of an application, in Typescript I could have:

```
const config = {
  applicationName: 'Some application',
  port: 8000,
};

const testOne = config.applicationName;
const testTwo = config.fail;             // this would not work
```

That is to say, the compiler, or some interpreter which the IDE uses, is able to tell based on the structure that a key/value does not exist for that structure.

It seems to me that a class is excessive for this kind of data; though as I'm relatively new to the language, this may be due to my naivety. I'd like to know if there's a structure within C# that can store keys and values, in an immutable way, and know at compile time whether or not a key/value pair is available in that collection.

Comment: Like in a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: Are you looking for a [ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: I don't think that the IDE/compiler checks the content of collections. Yes, you are looking to create a class.

Comment: Either a Dictionary or a ReadOnlyDictionary would work, but since you explicitly stated you want an immutable list of key/value pairs I'd suggest using an [ImmutableDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: Ah I guess I misunderstood your question. You want to know, before compiling if `myObj.PropertyThatDoesExist` the IDE will show you the error?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question. Did you try using a class? What C# code did you try that didn't give you this functionality? Also, by "would not work", what **exactly** do you mean? Compiler error? Runtime error? The reason I ask is that out of the box, if you use types with members, this would do exactly what you want. Just create a class with two properties, ApplicationName and Port, then you can't set arbitrary values on it.

Comment: *"where the IDE/compiler would know which keys are or aren't present in that list"* - enum or class with public (static?) members.

Comment: [The is an XY Problem (Question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  That is you're trying to solve a problem using a solution you have a question about instead of actually presenting the real problem.  You have all these requirements (like immutable) without describing why they are needed.  This is not a good question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't think it's an XY problem; I would _prefer_ to be able to structure data in an immutable way without using a class. I could update the question to make that clearer?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you for your help; it may well be that a class would be the best way of creating this, understanding whether a class is appropriate and necessary for storing this kind of data was kind of the purpose of my question. I think what confuses me is that it seems that the purpose of a class is not to create key/value stores, so to use one for this purpose seems inappropriate, but I'm new to the language

Comment: @mm8 I'll take a look at that, thank you

Comment: @Cid that's correct; I'll update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

```
var obj = new
{
    applicationName = "",
    port = 9000
};

var name = obj.applicationName;
var something = obj.fail; //doesn't compile
```

Although, I really encourage you to create classes and give them a name, as you can expose them from APIs.

Comment: How is this Immutable?

Comment: @ErikPhilips you are right, I missed that one. Now I updated the answer to reflect this issue.

Comment: This is a useful answer, I'll take a look into anonymous types and structs, and pending any further answers I'll accept this one as correct

Comment: @OliverRadini to answer your edited question: no, I don't think that there is such a structure both immutable and anonymous, at least not from what I have seen in my experience with C# until now.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Thanks! It seems as though it will be a case of picking from a number of less than ideal alternatives and an anonymous type may be the best option

Comment: @OliverRadini I thank you also, but I still encourage you to open a new question regarding what you want to accomplish now with anonymous types and see what other suggestions you can get.

Comment: @meJustAndrew anonymous types are actually _fairly_ immutable; you cannot modify the values, but you can reassign the variable, which for my purposes suits me fine, so really these achieve exactly what I need